# Error en Navbar, routing react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Tengo un inconveniente con el navbar y el routing de los productos de mi ecommerce.

No  me muestra el menu desplegable de mi navbar.

Tengo un json con los productos y tengo un componente Navbar

```html
<ul className="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
    <li>
        <Link to="/tipo/Cortos" className="text-decoration-none">
        <a className="dropdown-item">
            Cortos
        </a>
        </Link>
    </li>
    <li>
        <Link to="/tipo/Largos" className="text-decoration-none">
        <a className="dropdown-item">
            Largos
        </a>
        </Link>
    </li>
    <li>
        <Link to="/tipo/MediaEstacion" className="text-decoration-none">
        <a className="dropdown-item">
            Media Estacion
        </a>
        </Link>
    </li>
    <li>
        <hr className="dropdown-divider" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <Link to="/productos" className="text-decoration-none">
        <a className="dropdown-item">
            Todos los Productos
        </a>
        </Link>
    </li>
```

Necesitaria ayuda para poder linkearlo y mostrar cada subdivision-

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: como primera medida debes cerrar el ul, como segunda, para que usas etiquetas a? los link cumplen con este cometido. Yo probe el menu con las modificiones y funciona